# Left Join with Where clause returns empty result

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have got a `post` table and it's schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` longtext COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_5A8A6C8DA76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_5A8A6C8DF6BD1646` (`site_id`),
  KEY `IDX_5A8A6C8D727ACA70` (`parent_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=16620 ;
```

I'm using this DQL to fetch a post and it's children:

```
$post = $this->_diContainer->wordy_app_doctrine->fetch(
           "SELECT p,c FROM Wordy\Entity\Post p LEFT JOIN p.children c WHERE p.site = :site AND p.id = :id AND p.language = :language AND p.status != 'trashed'  AND c.status != 'trashed' ORDER BY c.title",
           array(
               'params' => array(
               'id' => $id,
               'site' => $this->_currentSite['id'],
               'language' => $this->_currentLanguage->code,
           )
       )
   );
```

What i'm trying to do is: Fetch a post and all of it's children. The criteria is, don't include trashed posts or trashed children.

But when i run this query with a post which doesn't even have children, the returned result set is empty.

When i remove the `c.status != 'trashed'` part from query, everything works fine but i will get trashed posts too.

Thanks, in advance.

edit: here is the SQL output of given DQL:

```
SELECT p0_.id AS id0, p0_.title AS title5, p0_.status AS status8, p0_.parent_id AS parent_id9, p1_.id AS id15, p1_.title AS title20, p1_.status AS status23, p1_.parent_id AS parent_id24 FROM post p0_ LEFT JOIN post p1_ ON p0_.id = p1_.parent_id WHERE p0_.site_id = ? AND p0_.id = ? AND p0_.language = ? AND p0_.status <> 'trashed' ORDER BY p1_.title ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i solved my own problem.

Just use a `with` clause on `join` field instead of `where` clause, like this:

```
"SELECT p,c FROM Wordy\Entity\Post p LEFT JOIN p.children c WITH c.status != 'trashed' WHERE p.site = :site........."
```

Answer (score 1):

Your long conditional WHERE is being AND'ed together after the join and nothing is passing all the checks.  Move the join stuff into the ON clause and leave the c.trashed check in the WHERE clause. Try something like this:

```
SELECT p,c FROM Wordy\Entity\Post p LEFT JOIN children c ON p.site = :site AND p.id = :id AND p.language = :language AND p.status != 'trashed' AND p.id = c.parent_id  WHERE   c.status != 'trashed' ORDER BY c.title
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not SQL, it's DQL and Doctrine doesn't support ON clause: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: @cnkt Ah, DQL... your not required to use DQL with doctrine, you can specify a raw query. That might be the easiest thing to do in this case for what you're trying.  There probably is a DQL way to do it though, but I avoid DQL like the plague :)

Comment: Thanks, i will look for a way to do it with DQL. :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `ON` clause of the [left join syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).